# Test whether a glass prevents you from getting your Vitamin D portion?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, home-experiment, frequency, absorption

I work in an office with glass, which [I believe filters the UV radiation of the sunlight](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2088824). 
Is it possible to test if exposure to the light coming through the glass will supply Vitamin D for me as a mammal?

Comment: If your employer doesn't supply you with sunscreen then you aren't getting the light that will stimulate vitamin D production.

Comment: If you were sitting in the Sun all day being irradiated by UV light, your employer (unless you are in a country with significantly slacker H+S rules than the UK) would need to prevent you being sunburned.

Comment: You will also need to shower a lot less to get enough vitamin D, at which point nobody will want to be in the office with you...

Comment: If I recall properly (its been a while), the precursors are secreted through the skin, undergo the conversion to vitamin D on the surface, and then are reabsorbed by the body.  Showering regularly gets rid of the precursors, so you don't end up with much vitamin D.

Comment: @RobJeffries In the US and the UK, it seems that employers do not need to pay for sunscreen for outdoor employees. For the US, see the third bullet point in the list of exemptions on page 2 of this OSHA document: https://www.osha.gov/dte/outreach/intro_osha/7_employee_ppe.pdf . For the UK, see the "ultraviolet radiation from the sun" question in this FAQ: http://www.hse.gov.uk/radiation/nonionising/faqs.htm

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The wavelengths that stimulate vitamin D production are between 280nm and 320nm, which is called UVB. You would need to use a detector capable of measuring light in this wavelength.

However there is no need, because normal windows are made from soda-lime glass and this transmits no wavelengths shorter than about 350nm. Some Googling will find you the relevant absorption spectrum. [I found this example here](http://publiclab.org/wiki/uv-spectrometry):

[image: Glass absorption]

The plot shows that soda-lime glass doesn't transmit any UVB. Unless your office uses borosilicate or pure quartz windows (which is highly unlikely) you'll need to get outside to get your vitamin D fix.

Comment: You can test this with some UV sensitive beads: http://www.amazon.com/Original-Solaractive%C2%AE-Color-Changing-Beads/dp/B00506DWT0 (Note: This isn't the most precise test, but hey, it's inexpensive.)